# Celery node fail, on pidbox already using on restart

Tags: rabbitmq, celeryd

I have Celery running with RabbitMQ broker.
Today, I have a failure of a Celery node, it doesn't execute tasks and doesn't respond on `service celeryd stop` command. After few repeats, the node stopped, but on start I get this message:

```
[WARNING/MainProcess] celery@nodename ready.
[WARNING/MainProcess] /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/project_1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py:73: UserWarning: A node named u'nodename' is already using this process mailbox!

Maybe you forgot to shutdown the other node or did not do so properly?
Or if you meant to start multiple nodes on the same host please make sure
you give each node a unique node name!

  warnings.warn(W_PIDBOX_IN_USE % {'hostname': self.hostname})
```

Can anyone suggest how to unlock process mailbox?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Large log file or not enough free space was a reason, i think.
After deletion all is ok

Comment: I can confirm Jamal's answer.  It seems that RabbitMQ requires as much free disk space as RAM.  We got very low on disk space on the box -- when we cleared up lots of space, this message stopped occurring

Comment: I have the same problem, and deleted all the logs and checked the space on disk. It seems all good, but I keep getting the same error...

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See @f01 answer for correct explanation. I was also having the same problem and was solved using the explanation given in the link in the that answer.

Comment: @Jamal, you are probably confusing different issues because your tests were not isolated. You probably had an already-running process when you started another one, got your error. You stopped the original one and you also deleted for new "space", and it got fixed, making you think it was due to the free space.

Comment: This actually worked for me as well. I think he should've specified that you should be freeing space in the rabbitmq server (I was using amqp)

Comment: Where would this log file be located?

Answer (score 45):

From here http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#starting-the-worker you might need to name each node uniquely. Example:

```
$ celery -A proj worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n worker1.%h
```

In supervisor escape by using `%%h`.

Comment: Note, if you don't use `--concurrency`, and instead rely on another service like `supervisor` to handle concurrency, this will still result in conflicting node names.