# Django Celery Worker Not reciving the Tasks

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

Whenever I am running the celery worker I am getting the warning

```
./manage.py celery worker -l info --concurrency=8
```

[image]

and if I am ignored this warning then my celery worker not receiving the celery beat tasks

After [googled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430322/4551608) I have also changed the worker name, but this time I am not receiving the warning but celery worker still not receiving the celery beat scheduled tasks

I have checked the celery beat logs, and celery beat scheduling the task on time.

I have also checked the celery flower and its showing two workers and the first worker is receiving the tasks and not executing it, how to send all task the second worker? or how can i disable the first kombu worker, what is djagno-celery setting that i am missing?

My django settings.py

```
RABBITMQ_USERNAME = "guest"
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://%s:%s@localhost:5672//' % (RABBITMQ_USERNAME, 
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'default'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
celery_enable_utc=True
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Comment: Have you checked that you don't run any strange background celery tasks that you don't know about? What do you get as output from `ps ax | grep celery` in your terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only enabled the worker. For a task to be executed, you must call the task with the help of the `your_task.delay ()` function. 
For example, open another terminal, enter your project, and run the `python manage.py shell` command. When entering the shell of your project Django, import your task and run the command `your_task.delay ()`
In the following link, there is an example of celery code with rabbitmq broker, I advise you to study it:
https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django